# How to go from 12VAC to a micro USB cable

Tags: usb

I have a 12VAC dynamo I am planning to put on my bike and I want to know how to transfer the electricity generated into a Micro USB cable or USB port. There are devices out there costing upwards of $100 to do this but I want to know if there is a cheaper way for me to construct something like this.

UPDATE:

The design I had and device I had originally designed worked, I was just using a faulty USB cable.

Comment: easily found on the bay of fleas - have you looked?

Comment: 1st specify Isc and Voc for short and open circuit in your desired speed range. Then max load power

Comment: what voltage are you trying to produce?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are starting with AC the first thing is to rectify it into DC.  A bridge rectifier is good for that.  Now that you have DC (albeit lumpy), you will want to add some bulk capacitance (to remove the lumps). Then finally use a DC-DC converter to convert the 17Vdc into 5vdc.  *WAIT, WHAT?  17Vdc?*

The answer is purposely kept high level and general to encourage learning and discovery on your own.  Also how 12Vac becomes 17Vdc is an exercise for the student.